# Display X clients on from Ubuntu host on Cygwin box through VPN

Tags: ssh, xserver

Host A: Ubuntu Desktop box running at graphical runlevel. Sitting in office. /etc/ssh/sshd_config "X11Forwarding yes"

Host B: Windows laptop running Cygwin/X. Can run X clients locally. VPN from Host B into office network.
Can ssh from Host B to Host A. Want to display X clients on laptop.

From laptop:

```
xhost +
ssh -X mmartinez@hostA xclock
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
Error: Can't open display:
```

UPDATE: as per Michael Hampton's comment, using `ssh -Y mmartinez@10.10.10.165 xclock` works.

Comment: [This Link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/x11-forwarding-failed-872212/) suggests you make sure `xorg-x11-xauth` is installed on the remote system (the one serving X, not the one displaying it).

Comment: @MichaelHampton As per your link, top answer `ssh -Y mmartinez@10.10.10.165 xclock` worked. Thanks.